# Projeto importado do Eclipse para AndroidStudio não tem referencia R

Tags: android, android-studio

Importei um projeto do `Eclipse` para `Android Studio`, porém ele não tem referência para o antigo `R`.

Comment: FIle -> Invalidade Caches/Restart. Se não funcionar verifica o importe se está correto

Comment: Não deu. Vou tentar importar novamente. Quando eu crio um novo projeto, não da problema nenhum!

Comment: Não resolveu! :(

Answer (score 0):

Execute os seguintes passos:

1. Abra o Android Studio (Versão mais atualizada v1.0.2 [ATUALMENTE]);
2. Selecione a opção -> `NON ANDROID STUDIO PROJECT;`
3. Navegue até a pasta do seu projeto Eclipse e selecione-o;
4. Aguarde o build através do Gradle;
5. Sincronize o Gradle após configuração do projeto;
6. Pronto! :-)

Comment: Estou atualizando. Estava com a 1.0.1, assim que terminar farei o teste e posto o resultado aqui!

Comment: Atualizei, Importei novamente o projeto. Fiz todos os passos que vc disse. Sem sucesso. o R não tem referencia; não tem lógica!

Comment: Importei um outro projeto que não tem nada. é apenas novo. Ele deu certo, agora esse outro ta dando erro nessa referencia

Comment: Coloca o erro aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Uma das causas possíveis é algum problema sintático em um dos seus XML.

Lembre-se que o arquivo R.java é um arquivo gerado para permitir que os seus códigos Java referenciem elementos do XML. Quando há um problema no XML, o arquivo R não pode ser gerado e, portanto, não pode ser importado.